# Factor in Eisenstein Integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, eisenstein-integers

I wonder if there is a way to factor a number in $\mathbb{Z[\omega]}$ more "general"?, I currently use $(a+b\omega)(a+b\omega^2) = a^2 - ab + b^2 = \frac{(2a-b)^2 + 3b^2}{4}$ to find for example:

$13=(3+4\omega)(3+4{\omega}^2)$

but I have some issues with other numbers like $19$.

Comment: Have you constructed a list of all small prime numbers?  If you have a way to sort these numbers, perhaps by norm, you can use Eratosthenes's sieve on the sorted list to (1) find the primes and (2) find the factors of any number on the list.  Of course, $19$ is a prime integer, so the norm of its divisors in a number field are severely limited.

Comment: For prime $p > 2$, $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-3}]/(p) \cong \mathbf Z[\omega]/(p)$ since $\mathbf F_p[t]/(t^2+3) \cong \mathbf F_p[u]/(u^2+u+1)$.  So if you want to know whether $p$ is prime of composite in $\mathbf Z[\omega]$ then it's the same as knowing if $-3 \bmod p$ is not a square or is a square in $\mathbf F_p$, which corresponds to$ p \equiv 2 \bmod 3$ or $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$, respectively. That tells you the way $p$ factors but not an explicit decomposition if $p$ is reducible in $\mathbf Z[\omega]$.

Comment: 1) It is maybe useful to recall to newcomers that $\omega:=e^{2i \pi/3}$. 2) Your question could be formulated as the search for an efficient **algorithm** for factorization by hand (and pencil...) ; unless you consider using a computer which would be quite normal...

Comment: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/EisensteinFactorInteger/

Answer (score 2):

A good way to factor reducible natural primes $p$ (meaning $3$ and primes one greater than a multiple of $3$) is to first seek the unique form

$p=m^2+3n^2; m, n\in\mathbb Z_{\ge0}$

Then we render

$p=(m+n\sqrt{-3})(m-n\sqrt{-3})=[(m+n)+2n\omega][(m-n)-2n\omega]$

where the second link in the equality chain comes from rendering $\sqrt{-3}=2\omega+1$.

The two factors are of course conjugates of each other, so the second factor may be rendered as the conjugate of the first or vice versa. This gives two additional factorizations

$p=[(m+n)+2n\omega][(m+n)+2n\omega^2]=[(m-n)-2n\omega^2][(m-n)-2n\omega]$

Note that the coefficient on $\omega$ or $\omega^2$ will always be even, while (for prime or more generally odd inputs) the real terms will be odd.

Thus for instance $19=4^2+(3×1^2)$ gives

$19=(4+\sqrt{-3})(4-\sqrt{-3})=(5+2\omega)(3-2\omega)$

$=(5+2\omega)(5+2\omega^2)=(3-2\omega^2)(3-2\omega).$

Comment: potentially of interest: [For Eisenstein numbers $a + b\frac{1+\sqrt{3} i}{2}$ with $0 \le a, b \le n$ how can I efficiently identify all of the primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4688649/284619)