# For Eisenstein numbers $a + b\frac{1+\sqrt{3} i}{2}$ with $0 \le a, b \le n$ how can I efficiently identify all of the primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, eisenstein-integers

[This answer to *determining if a coincident point in a pair of rotated hexagonal lattices is closest to the origin?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3829536/284619) teaches that my real question was how to find if two [Eisenstein integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer) are [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers).

The answer outlines in great detail how to implement the [Euclidian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) for Eisenstein integers.

It begins:

> Set $u := \frac{1+\sqrt{3} i}{2}$. Consider the set $\{a+bu\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Since $u^2=u-1$, a product of two such numbers belongs to this set as well. I will denote this set $\mathbb{Z}[u]$.<sup>[1]</sup>
>
> [1] Actually, $\mathbb{Z}[u]$ means the set of all numbers of the form $a_0+a_1u+\dots+a_ku^k$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and $a_0,\dots,a_k\in \mathbb{Z}$; but since $u^2=u-1$, this is the set I described.

*If* I was now interested in first testing each Eisenstein integer separately first to see if it was prime, *how would I do that* short of checking to see if it was coprime with a large number of other Eisenstein integers?

**Question:** For Eisenstein numbers $a + b\frac{1+\sqrt{3} i}{2}$ with $0 \le a, b \le n$ how can I efficiently identify all of the primes?

Is there an algorithm similar/related to the Euclidian algorithm that I could use to test each number without exhaustively excluding all possible coprimes? Or perhaps a completely different algorithm?

---

[image: Eisenstein-Jacobi Primes from Unsolved Problems in Number Theory Third Edition, Richard K. Guy, Springer, 2004, (A16 Gaussian and Eisenstein-Jacobi primes, pp 55-57)] click for larger

Eisenstein-Jacobi Primes from *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory* Third Edition, Richard K. Guy, Springer, 2004, (A16 Gaussian and Eisenstein-Jacobi primes, pp 55-57)

Comment: That's a weird graphic! When I read the text above and below it, I get the distinct impression that the central cluster is moving.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_integer#Eisenstein_primes

Comment: @Micah I found that hard to follow, but I did subsequently find the following on Chris K. Caldwell's site [Fig. 49 on page 157](https://www.utm.edu/staff/caldwell/book/images/157.pdf) "Eisenstein primes come in three flavors: the prime $1−\omega$; the primes $\pm a, \pm a\omega$ and $\pm a\omega^2$, where $a$ is a real prime congruent to 2 modulo 3; and $a \pm b\omega$, where $a^2 - ab + b^2$ is a real prime" which, if I understand correctly, could be the basis of an answer if suitably explained and supported.

Comment: related in HSM SE: [How did Gaussian and Eisenstein integers get their names?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12560/3869)

Answer (score 2):

Call an Eisenstein integer a good number if it is $a+bu$ for some nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$, where $u=a+b\frac{1+\sqrt3i}2$. If we split the entire complex plane into six equal sectors by lines $x=0$, $y=ux$ and $y=u^2x$, the good number are the Eisenstein numbers that are in the same sector as $1+u$.

##### An algorithm that checks if a good number is an Eisenstein prime

Here is the algorithm that determines whether a good number $a+bu$ is an Eisenstein prime.

1. If $a=b=1$, return True.
2. If $b=0$ and $a$ is an ordinary prime number that is $2\,\text{mod}\,3$, return TRUE.
3. If $a\not=b\pmod3$ and $a^2+ab+b^2$ is an ordinary prime number, return TRUE.
4. Return FALSE.

(Step 1 and step 2 can be combined as one step: If $a^2+ab+b^2$ is an ordinary prime number, return TRUE.)

The time-complexity of the algorithm depends on how we compute whether an ordinary integer is prime. Suppose we use the most common and simple way by checking whether it is a multiple of an integer at least 2 and at most the square root of it. Then the time-complexity of the algorithm is $O(\max(a,b))$.

##### List all prime good numbers a+bu where $0\le a,b\le n$

A simple algorithm is just listing all those good numbers and one by one checking if it is an Eisenstein prime as above. The time-complexity is $O(n^3)$.

Here is a faster algorithm, the time-complexity of which is $O(n^2\log \log n)$ if an ordinary Eratosthenes sieve is used to list ordinary primes numbers. If we use [a linear sieve](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/prime-sieve-linear.html) instead, the time-complexity is $O(n^2)$.

1. Output $1+u$.
2. Output $p+0u$ and $0+pu$ for each ordinary prime number $p\le n$ that is $2\,\text{mod}\,3$.
3. Compute the set of all ordinary prime numbers $\le 3n^2$.
   For each pairs of positive numbers $(a,b)$ such that $a<b$ and $a^2+ab+b^2$ is a member of that set, output $a+bu$ and $b+au$.

Comment: This is great I'll give it a test drive today, thanks! I think I can verify my implementation by plotting those little hexagonal spots that others do when describing Eisenstein integers and matching the pattern and counting them. fyi related in HSM SE: [How did Gaussian and Eisenstein integers get their names?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12560/3869)

Answer (score 1):

This can be enumerated in some effective manner.

We know that the norm $$N(a+b\omega)=\left(a+b\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)\right)\left(a+b\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right)\right)=a^2+ab+b^2$$.

Now, if we know $|a|,|b|<n$ so $N(a+b\phi)\leq 3n^2$.

For each prime $p\in \mathbb{Z}$, that sits inside the interval $[0,3n^2]$, you can test whether $p$ is an irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$.

If not, $p=(a+b\omega)(a+b\bar{\omega})$ and then $a+b\omega$ (and $a+b\bar{\omega}=a+b\omega^2=(a-b)-b\omega$) are irreducibles in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. Now you can test whether these coefficients do sit inside your given interval.